# Prove that inequality $1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals, harmonic-functions, telescopic-series

Let $n$ is a natural number. Prove that inequality $$1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{2}$$

---

**My try:** $$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\left(n-1\right)}=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$

Please check my solution for me and give me some idea.

Comment: Before your last inequality, you have a term $\left(\frac{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)$ that you drop (perhaps you think it is less than $1$?), but it should be present in the last term, or bounded above by some constant.

Comment: Oh i realized it, i will try another idea thanks.

Comment: You could get a whole family of proofs by showing that $\sum^n<\sum^\infty = \zeta(3/2)=2.612<2\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We may consider that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have
$$ f(n-1/2)-f(n+1/2) \geq -f'(n) $$
or
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1/2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1/2}} \geq \frac{1}{2n\sqrt{n}} $$
such that by creative telescoping
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-1/2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1/2}}\right) < 2\sqrt{2}.$$
The inequality is pretty sharp since $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=2.612375\ldots$
The same approach proves $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\leq 1+2\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}<2.633$.

Comment: What a nice solution!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry for the (maybe stupid) question I'm trying to complete a proof by induction using your ideas but I don't get the application for convexity here $$f(n-1/2)-f(n+1/2) \geq -f'(n) \iff f'(n)\le f(n+1/2)-f(n-1/2)$$ but I only can get  that $$f'(n-1/2)\le f(n+1/2)-f(n-1/2)$$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gimusi: a straightforward proof comes from considering the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin: all its coefficients are clearly non-negative, so for any $x\geq 0$ we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}\geq \frac{x}{n\sqrt{n}}$ and it is enough to consider $x=1/2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks! Then it doesn't come directly from convexity? am I right?

Comment: @gimusi: it *does* come from the convexity of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+x}}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok thanks again, I will revise the subject!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok now it seems clear, we are using that $\frac1{2n\sqrt {n}}<f'(0)=\frac2{n\sqrt {n}}\le f(1/2)-f(0)$.

Answer (score 5):

Your sum can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}=1+2^{-3/2}+\sum_{k=3}^n k^{-3/2}$. Since $f(x)=x^{-3/2}$ is decreasing, we can bound the sum from above by an integral, that is,

$$
\sum_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}\leq\int_2^n x^{-3/2}\,dx.
$$
Note specifically the lower bound of the integral.

Evaluating the integral on the right yields
$$
\int_2^n x^{-3/2}\,dx=-2x^{-1/2}\bigg|_{x=2}^{x=n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt n}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\leq1+2^{-3/2}+\frac{2}{\sqrt2}-\frac2{\sqrt n}\leq\frac{2^{3/2}+1+4}{2^{3/2}}.
$$
Clearly $2^{3/2}=2\sqrt2=\sqrt8\leq\sqrt9=3$, so that we have
$$
\frac{2^{3/2}+1+4}{2^{3/2}}\leq\frac{8}{2^{3/2}}=2\sqrt2.
$$
Putting it all together, then, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-3/2}\leq2\sqrt2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

I think your way gets something wrong.

By your work:

For all $n\geq2$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}<\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}
{\sqrt{n}}\right)\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}}=$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\right)\leq\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)(1+\sqrt2).$$
Thus, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}\leq1+(1+\sqrt2)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$1+(1+\sqrt2)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)<2\sqrt2,$$ which is wrong for $n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The original inequality cannot be proved directly by induction but by the solution given by [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2876263/505767) is interesting to note that we can also proceed by induction proving the stronger result

$$1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac12}}<2\sqrt{2}$$

indeed it is true for $n=1$ since

$$1<2\sqrt 2-2\sqrt{\frac23}\approx 1.20$$

and by induction step we obtain

$$1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}\stackrel{Hyp.}<2\sqrt{2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac12}}+\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}\stackrel{?}<2\sqrt{2}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac32}}$$

which is true indeed

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac12}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+\frac32}} \iff \frac{1}{2n\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-\frac12}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+\frac12}}$$

and by convexity of $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt {n-x}}-\frac1{\sqrt {n+x}}$ we have

$$f'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt {(n-x)^3}}+\frac1{\sqrt {(n+x)^3}}$$

$$\frac1{2n\sqrt {n}}<f'(0)=\frac2{n\sqrt {n}}\le f(1/2)-f(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-\frac12}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+\frac12}}$$